# Restart a function if there is no click, or touch event on screen

Tags: javascript, memory, touch, detection

I found this code on net, it's about a memory game.

```html
var MemoryApp = (function () {
   'use strict';
   var size = 36;
   var sizeStyle = "smallGame";
   var maxpics = 18;
   var gameRunning = false;
   var cardOpen = null;
   var time = 0;
   var timer;
   var s4;
   var s6;
   var s8;
   var attempts = 0;
   var found = 0;
   var foundDisp;
   var attDisp;
   var timeDisp;
   var template;
   var popupImage;
   var popupHolder;
   var gameGrid;
   var currentCardSet = 'zoo';
   var currentCards = [];
   window.onload = runGame;

   function activated() {
      WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function(){
         s4 = document.getElementById("size4x4");
         s6 = document.getElementById("size6x6");
         s8 = document.getElementById("size8x8");
         s4.addEventListener("click", gameSize, false);
         s6.addEventListener("click", gameSize, false);
         s8.addEventListener("click", gameSize, false);

         var start = document.getElementById("startGame");
         if (start) {
            start.onclick = runGame;
         }
         var stop = document.getElementById("stopGame");
         if (stop) {
            stop.onclick = stopGame;
         }

         template = document.getElementById("cardTemplate");

         popupImage = document.getElementById("popupImage");
         popupHolder = document.getElementById("popupHolder");
         popupHolder.addEventListener("click", closeImageView, false);

         foundDisp = document.getElementById("foundDisplay");
         attDisp = document.getElementById("attemptsDisplay");
         timeDisp = document.getElementById("timeDisplay");

         // Expose functions globally
         window.updateClock = updateClock;
         window.resetCards = resetCards;
         window.gameTag1 = null;
         window.gameTag2 = null;

         buildCards();
      });
   }

   function closeImageView() {
      removeClass(popupHolder, "openImagePopup");
   }

   function makePictureArray() {
      var pics = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < maxpics; i++) {
         pics[i] = getDefaultURL(i);
      }
      return pics;
   }

   function removeAllChildren(element) {
      if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
         while (element.childNodes.length > 0) {
            element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
         }
      }
   }

   function buildCards() {
   // Assumption: game grid size is a power of 2
      var stride = Math.sqrt(size);

      // Make picture selection
      var pics = makePictureArray();
      var sel = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
         var idx = parseInt(Math.random() * pics.length);
         sel[i] = pics[idx];
         // remove the used pic
         pics.splice(idx, 1);
      }

      // get an array with the card content
      var content = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
         content[i] = sel[i];
         content[i + size / 2] = sel[i];
      }

      var gameBoard = document.querySelector('#gameBoard');
      removeAllChildren(gameBoard);
      var gameGrid = document.createElement("div");
      gameGrid.id = "gameGrid";
      addClass(gameGrid, sizeStyle);
      gameBoard.appendChild(gameGrid);

      for (var i=0; i<size; i++) {
         var item = document.createElement("div");
         item.className = "gameItem"+i;
         item.addEventListener("click", cardClicked, false);
         setClosed(item);

         var r = parseInt(Math.random() * content.length);

         // Add image
         insertTemplate(item, template);
         var walker = document.createTreeWalker(item, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, imgFilter, false);
         while (walker.nextNode())
            walker.currentNode.setAttribute("src", content[r]);
      
         // Add path to ease styling
         var walker = document.createTreeWalker(item, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, pFilter, false);
         while (walker.nextNode())
            walker.currentNode.innerText = content[r];

         item.contentIndex = content[r];
         content.splice(r, 1);
         gameGrid.appendChild(item);
      }
   }

   function imgFilter(node) {
      if (node.tagName == "IMG") //filter IMG elements
         return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
      else
         return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP
   }

   function pFilter(node) {
      if (node.tagName == "P") //filter IMG elements
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
         else
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP
   }

   function insertTemplate(parent, templateParent) {
      if (templateParent.children && templateParent.children.length >= 1) {
         var tchild = templateParent.children[0].cloneNode(true);
         parent.appendChild(tchild);
      } 
   }

   function gameSize() {
      document.size.size4x4.checked = false;
      document.size.size6x6.checked = false;
      document.size.size8x8.checked = false;

      var newsize = 36;
      var gSize = "smallGame";
         if (this.name == "size4x4") {
            document.size.size4x4.checked = true;
            newsize = 36;
         gSize = "smallGame";
      }
      if (this.name == "size6x6") {
         document.size.size6x6.checked = true;
         newsize = 36;
         gSize = "mediumGame";
      }
      if (this.name == "size8x8") {
         document.size.size8x8.checked = true;
         newsize = 36;
         gSize = "largeGame";
      }
      if (!gameRunning == true) {
         size = newsize;
         sizeStyle = gSize;
         buildCards();
      }
   }
   
   function stopGame() {
      if (!gameRunning)
         return;
      gameRunning = false;
      foundDisp.innerText = "0";
      found = 0;
      attDisp.innerText = "0";
      attempts = 0;
      clearInterval(timer);
      timeDisp.innerText = "00:00";
      s4.disabled = false;
      s6.disabled = false;
      s8.disabled = false;
   }

   function runGame() {
      //don't do anything if game already running
      if (gameRunning == true)
         return;
      window.gameTag1 = null;
      window.gameTag2 = null;
      cardOpen = null;
      gameRunning = true;
      buildCards();
      timeDisp.innerText = "00:00";
      time = 0;
      foundDisp.innerText = "0";
      found = 0;
      attDisp.innerText = "0";
      attempts = 0;
      timer = setInterval("updateClock()", 1000);
      s4.disabled = true;
      s6.disabled = true;
      s8.disabled = true;
   }

   function getDefaultURL(i) {
      var idx = i+1;
      if (idx<1)
         idx = 1;
      if (idx>32)
         idx = 32;
      var result = "/photos/" + currentCardSet + "/";
      if (idx < 10)
         result = result + "0";
      result = result + idx.toString() + ".jpg";
      return result;
   }

   function updateClock() {
      time = time + 1;
      var mins = parseInt(time / 60);
      var secs = time - mins * 60;

      mins = mins.toString();
      secs = secs.toString();

      if (mins.length < 2)
         mins = "0" + mins;
      if (secs.length < 2)
         secs = "0" + secs;

      timeDisp.innerText = mins + ":" + secs;
   }

   function cardClicked() {

      // If an open card is clicked, bring up the full size popup
      if (this.cardFoundFlag || cardOpen === this) {
         popupImage.setAttribute("src", this.contentIndex);
         popupHolder.style.display = "block";
         addClass(popupHolder, "openImagePopup");
         return;
      }

      // don't do anything if no game is running, or a move is in play...
      if (!gameRunning || window.gameTag1 !=null || window.gameTag2 != null)
         return;
      
      if (cardOpen == null) {
         setOpen(this);
         cardOpen = this;
      } else {
         if (this.contentIndex == cardOpen.contentIndex) {
            setFound(this);
            setFound(cardOpen);
            this.cardFoundFlag = true;
            cardOpen.cardFoundFlag = true;
            cardOpen = null;
            found++;
            foundDisp.innerText = found;
            updateAttempts();
            if (found == size / 2) {
               gameRunning = false;
               clearInterval(timer);
               foundDisp.innerText = "ALL!";
            }
         } else {
            setOpen(this);
            // Hack to get around insulation of these functions
            window.gameTag1 = this;
            window.gameTag2 = cardOpen;
            setTimeout("resetCards()", 1100);
            cardOpen = null;
            updateAttempts();
         }
      }
   }

   function setOpen(el) {
      removeClass(el, "closedCard");
      addClass(el, "openCard");
   }

   function setClosed(el) {
      removeClass(el, "openCard");
      addClass(el, "closedCard");
   }

   function setFound(el) {
      removeClass(el, "openCard");
      removeClass(el, "closedCard");
      addClass(el, "foundCard");
   }

   function resetCardStyles(el) {
         removeClass(el, "openCard");
         removeClass(el, "foundCard");
         addClass(el, "closedCard");
   }

   function updateAttempts() {
         attempts++;
         attDisp.innerText = attempts;
   }

   function resetAllCards() {
         buildCards();
   }

   function resetCards() {
      setClosed(window.gameTag1);
      setClosed(window.gameTag2);
      window.gameTag1 = null;
      window.gameTag2 = null;
   }

   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // Utilities
   //
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   function hasClass(el, className) {
      // authors can pass in either an element object or an ID
      el = (typeof (el) == 'object') ? el : document.getElementById(el);

      // no need to continue if there's no className
      if (!el.className) return false;

      // iterate through all the classes
      var classArray = el.className.split(' ');
      for (var i = 0; i < classArray.length; i++) {
         if (className == classArray[i]) return true; // found? return true
      }

      // if we're still here, the class does not exist
      return false;
   }

   function addClass(el, className) {
      // authors can pass in either an element object or an ID
      el = (typeof (el) == 'object') ? el : document.getElementById(el);

      // simply append the className to the string
      el.className += ' ' + className;
      return;
   }

   function removeClass(el, className) {
      // authors can pass in either an element object or an ID
      el = (typeof (el) == 'object') ? el : document.getElementById(el);

      // if the class doesn't exist, there's no need to remove it
      if (!hasClass(el, className)) return;

      // iterate through all the classes
      var classArray = el.className.split(' ');
      for (var i = 0; i < classArray.length; i++) {

         // found it!
         if (className == classArray[i]) {
            classArray.splice(i, 1); // remove it
            i--; // decrement so we don't skip over any future occurences
         }
      }

      // reassign the className
      el.className = classArray.join(' ');
      return;
   }

   WinJS.Application.onactivated = function (e) {
      if (e.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
         activated();
      }
   }

   WinJS.Application.start();
});

var theMemoryApp = new MemoryApp();
```

I need to add a function which is going to check for touch or click detection on the screen. If there is no touch after some seconds, all game has to restart from the beginning. How can I do that?

I hide that start and stop buttons on the design. So with `window.onload=runGame` game starts automatically when its loaded. But need to be restart if children live the game play when its not finished. For example, if there is no touch after 120 seconds, all code has to restart from beginning. Or there is buildCard function in the code. This timer can trigger this function also. I will be glad for any kind of help cause this is for kids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use debounce technique like shown in below snippet. I have added click event but you can add touch specific events also. timer() will be triggered every 120 secs if click event is not triggered i.e if user doesn't click or touch. I could not run your code to test. Please let me know if this doesn't work.

```html
var MemoryApp = (function () {
   'use strict';
   var size = 36;
   var sizeStyle = "smallGame";
   var maxpics = 18;
   var gameRunning = false;
   var cardOpen = null;
   var time = 0;
   var timer;
   var s4;
   var s6;
   var s8;
   var attempts = 0;
   var found = 0;
   var foundDisp;
   var attDisp;
   var timeDisp;
   var template;
   var popupImage;
   var popupHolder;
   var gameGrid;
   var currentCardSet = 'zoo';
   var currentCards = [],
   __timeOut = 0;
   window.onload = runGame;

   var timer = function() {
      clearTimeout(__timeOut);
      __timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
         buildCards();
      }, 120000);
   };

   window.addEventListener('click', timer);

   function activated() {
      WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function(){
         s4 = document.getElementById("size4x4");
         s6 = document.getElementById("size6x6");
         s8 = document.getElementById("size8x8");
         s4.addEventListener("click", gameSize, false);
         s6.addEventListener("click", gameSize, false);
         s8.addEventListener("click", gameSize, false);

         var start = document.getElementById("startGame");
         if (start) {
            start.onclick = runGame;
         }
         var stop = document.getElementById("stopGame");
         if (stop) {
            stop.onclick = stopGame;
         }

         template = document.getElementById("cardTemplate");

         popupImage = document.getElementById("popupImage");
         popupHolder = document.getElementById("popupHolder");
         popupHolder.addEventListener("click", closeImageView, false);

         foundDisp = document.getElementById("foundDisplay");
         attDisp = document.getElementById("attemptsDisplay");
         timeDisp = document.getElementById("timeDisplay");

         // Expose functions globally
         window.updateClock = updateClock;
         window.resetCards = resetCards;
         window.gameTag1 = null;
         window.gameTag2 = null;

         buildCards();
      });
   }

   function closeImageView() {
      removeClass(popupHolder, "openImagePopup");
   }

   function makePictureArray() {
      var pics = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < maxpics; i++) {
         pics[i] = getDefaultURL(i);
      }
      return pics;
   }

   function removeAllChildren(element) {
      if (element.hasChildNodes()) {
         while (element.childNodes.length > 0) {
            element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
         }
      }
   }

   function buildCards() {
   // Assumption: game grid size is a power of 2
      var stride = Math.sqrt(size);

      // Make picture selection
      var pics = makePictureArray();
      var sel = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
         var idx = parseInt(Math.random() * pics.length);
         sel[i] = pics[idx];
         // remove the used pic
         pics.splice(idx, 1);
      }

      // get an array with the card content
      var content = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
         content[i] = sel[i];
         content[i + size / 2] = sel[i];
      }

      var gameBoard = document.querySelector('#gameBoard');
      removeAllChildren(gameBoard);
      var gameGrid = document.createElement("div");
      gameGrid.id = "gameGrid";
      addClass(gameGrid, sizeStyle);
      gameBoard.appendChild(gameGrid);

      for (var i=0; i<size; i++) {
         var item = document.createElement("div");
         item.className = "gameItem"+i;
         item.addEventListener("click", cardClicked, false);
         setClosed(item);

         var r = parseInt(Math.random() * content.length);

         // Add image
         insertTemplate(item, template);
         var walker = document.createTreeWalker(item, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, imgFilter, false);
         while (walker.nextNode())
            walker.currentNode.setAttribute("src", content[r]);
      
         // Add path to ease styling
         var walker = document.createTreeWalker(item, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, pFilter, false);
         while (walker.nextNode())
            walker.currentNode.innerText = content[r];

         item.contentIndex = content[r];
         content.splice(r, 1);
         gameGrid.appendChild(item);
      }
   }

   function imgFilter(node) {
      if (node.tagName == "IMG") //filter IMG elements
         return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
      else
         return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP
   }

   function pFilter(node) {
      if (node.tagName == "P") //filter IMG elements
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
         else
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP
   }

   function insertTemplate(parent, templateParent) {
      if (templateParent.children && templateParent.children.length >= 1) {
         var tchild = templateParent.children[0].cloneNode(true);
         parent.appendChild(tchild);
      } 
   }

   function gameSize() {
      document.size.size4x4.checked = false;
      document.size.size6x6.checked = false;
      document.size.size8x8.checked = false;

      var newsize = 36;
      var gSize = "smallGame";
         if (this.name == "size4x4") {
            document.size.size4x4.checked = true;
            newsize = 36;
         gSize = "smallGame";
      }
      if (this.name == "size6x6") {
         document.size.size6x6.checked = true;
         newsize = 36;
         gSize = "mediumGame";
      }
      if (this.name == "size8x8") {
         document.size.size8x8.checked = true;
         newsize = 36;
         gSize = "largeGame";
      }
      if (!gameRunning == true) {
         size = newsize;
         sizeStyle = gSize;
         buildCards();
      }
   }
   
   function stopGame() {
      if (!gameRunning)
         return;
      gameRunning = false;
      foundDisp.innerText = "0";
      found = 0;
      attDisp.innerText = "0";
      attempts = 0;
      clearInterval(timer);
      timeDisp.innerText = "00:00";
      s4.disabled = false;
      s6.disabled = false;
      s8.disabled = false;
   }

   function runGame() {
      //don't do anything if game already running
      if (gameRunning == true)
         return;
      window.gameTag1 = null;
      window.gameTag2 = null;
      cardOpen = null;
      gameRunning = true;
      buildCards();
      timeDisp.innerText = "00:00";
      time = 0;
      foundDisp.innerText = "0";
      found = 0;
      attDisp.innerText = "0";
      attempts = 0;
      timer = setInterval("updateClock()", 1000);
      s4.disabled = true;
      s6.disabled = true;
      s8.disabled = true;
   }

   function getDefaultURL(i) {
      var idx = i+1;
      if (idx<1)
         idx = 1;
      if (idx>32)
         idx = 32;
      var result = "/photos/" + currentCardSet + "/";
      if (idx < 10)
         result = result + "0";
      result = result + idx.toString() + ".jpg";
      return result;
   }

   function updateClock() {
      time = time + 1;
      var mins = parseInt(time / 60);
      var secs = time - mins * 60;

      mins = mins.toString();
      secs = secs.toString();

      if (mins.length < 2)
         mins = "0" + mins;
      if (secs.length < 2)
         secs = "0" + secs;

      timeDisp.innerText = mins + ":" + secs;
   }

   function cardClicked() {

      // If an open card is clicked, bring up the full size popup
      if (this.cardFoundFlag || cardOpen === this) {
         popupImage.setAttribute("src", this.contentIndex);
         popupHolder.style.display = "block";
         addClass(popupHolder, "openImagePopup");
         return;
      }

      // don't do anything if no game is running, or a move is in play...
      if (!gameRunning || window.gameTag1 !=null || window.gameTag2 != null)
         return;
      
      if (cardOpen == null) {
         setOpen(this);
         cardOpen = this;
      } else {
         if (this.contentIndex == cardOpen.contentIndex) {
            setFound(this);
            setFound(cardOpen);
            this.cardFoundFlag = true;
            cardOpen.cardFoundFlag = true;
            cardOpen = null;
            found++;
            foundDisp.innerText = found;
            updateAttempts();
            if (found == size / 2) {
               gameRunning = false;
               clearInterval(timer);
               foundDisp.innerText = "ALL!";
            }
         } else {
            setOpen(this);
            // Hack to get around insulation of these functions
            window.gameTag1 = this;
            window.gameTag2 = cardOpen;
            setTimeout("resetCards()", 1100);
            cardOpen = null;
            updateAttempts();
         }
      }
   }

   function setOpen(el) {
      removeClass(el, "closedCard");
      addClass(el, "openCard");
   }

   function setClosed(el) {
      removeClass(el, "openCard");
      addClass(el, "closedCard");
   }

   function setFound(el) {
      removeClass(el, "openCard");
      removeClass(el, "closedCard");
      addClass(el, "foundCard");
   }

   function resetCardStyles(el) {
         removeClass(el, "openCard");
         removeClass(el, "foundCard");
         addClass(el, "closedCard");
   }

   function updateAttempts() {
         attempts++;
         attDisp.innerText = attempts;
   }

   function resetAllCards() {
         buildCards();
   }

   function resetCards() {
      setClosed(window.gameTag1);
      setClosed(window.gameTag2);
      window.gameTag1 = null;
      window.gameTag2 = null;
   }

   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // Utilities
   //
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   function hasClass(el, className) {
      // authors can pass in either an element object or an ID
      el = (typeof (el) == 'object') ? el : document.getElementById(el);

      // no need to continue if there's no className
      if (!el.className) return false;

      // iterate through all the classes
      var classArray = el.className.split(' ');
      for (var i = 0; i < classArray.length; i++) {
         if (className == classArray[i]) return true; // found? return true
      }

      // if we're still here, the class does not exist
      return false;
   }

   function addClass(el, className) {
      // authors can pass in either an element object or an ID
      el = (typeof (el) == 'object') ? el : document.getElementById(el);

      // simply append the className to the string
      el.className += ' ' + className;
      return;
   }

   function removeClass(el, className) {
      // authors can pass in either an element object or an ID
      el = (typeof (el) == 'object') ? el : document.getElementById(el);

      // if the class doesn't exist, there's no need to remove it
      if (!hasClass(el, className)) return;

      // iterate through all the classes
      var classArray = el.className.split(' ');
      for (var i = 0; i < classArray.length; i++) {

         // found it!
         if (className == classArray[i]) {
            classArray.splice(i, 1); // remove it
            i--; // decrement so we don't skip over any future occurences
         }
      }

      // reassign the className
      el.className = classArray.join(' ');
      return;
   }

   WinJS.Application.onactivated = function (e) {
      if (e.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
         activated();
      }
   }

   WinJS.Application.start();
});

var theMemoryApp = new MemoryApp();
```

Comment: it works perect thank you! i just added var infornt of the __timeOut=0;